# How to pass SF from Activity to its Presenter with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I want to pass SharedPreferences instanse to Presenter from Activity with Kotlin. I`m using dagger 2 for inject. But I get error:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
>   sharedPref has not been initialized

With Java this code works, but not with Kotlin.

Code from Activity:

```
@Inject
lateinit var sharedPref : SharedPreferences

@InjectPresenter
lateinit var presenter: DataPresenter

@ProvidePresenter
fun providePresenter(): DataPresenter{
    return DataPresenter(sharedPref)
}
```

Presenter constructor:

```
@InjectViewState
class DataPresenter(mPreferences: SharedPreferences)
```

Comment: have you converte java file into kotlin?

Comment: @Hamza no, why?

Comment: Can you please show what code is working on Java?